# Need to get additional data in custom shipping method Magento 2?

Tags: magento2, shipping-methods

How can I get additional data in custom shipping method?

[image]

```
public function collectRates(RateRequest $request)
    {
        if (!$this->getConfigFlag('active')) {
            return false;
        }

        $this->configPhpSigep();
        $metodos = $this->calculaFreteCorreios($request);

        /** @var \Magento\Shipping\Model\Rate\Result $result */
        $result = $this->_rateResultFactory->create();
        $free_sheeping = $request->getFreeShipping();

        foreach ($metodos as $metodo) {

            /** @var \Magento\Quote\Model\Quote\Address\RateResult\Method $method */
            $method_colection = $this->_rateMethodFactory->create();

            $method_colection->setCarrier('correiosship');
            $method_colection->setCarrierTitle($metodo['nome']);
            $method_colection->setData('prazo', $metodo['prazo']);

            $method_colection->setMethod('correiosship_' . $metodo['codigo']);
            $method_colection->setMethodTitle($metodo['nome']);
//            $method_colection->setMethodTitle($metodo['nome'] . " Em média " . $metodo['prazo'] . " dia(s)");

            $method_colection->setPrice($metodo['valor_cliente']); // valor pago pelo cliente
            $method_colection->setCost($metodo['valor_lojista']); // valor pago pelo lojista
            $result->append($method_colection);
        }

        return $result;
    }
```

I set additional data with:

```
$method_colection->setData('prazo', $metodo['prazo']);
```

Now I need to render in template custom-method-item-template.html

```
<!-- Initialize collapsible binding -->
<tbody collapsible="as: '$collapsible_' + method.method_code">
<tr class="row">
    <td class="col col-method">
        <input type="radio"
               class="radio"
               click="element.selectShippingMethod"
               ifnot="method.error_message"
               ko-checked="element.isSelected"
               ko-value="method.carrier_code + '_' + method.method_code"
               attr="'aria-labelledby': 'label_method_' + method.method_code + '_' + method.carrier_code + ' ' + 'label_carrier_' + method.method_code + '_' + method.carrier_code,
                        'checked': element.rates().length == 1 || element.isSelected" />
    </td>

    <td class="col col-method"
        attr="'id': 'label_method_' + method.method_code + '_' + method.carrier_code"
        text="method.method_title" />
    <td class="col col-price">
        <each args="element.getRegion('price')" render="" />
    </td>
    <!-- Need to render additional data here -->
    <td data-bind="text: method.prazo"></td>
    <!--<td class="col col-carrier"-->
        <!--attr="'id': 'label_carrier_' + method.method_code + '_' + method.carrier_code"-->
        <!--text="method.carrier_title" />-->
</tr>
<!-- Row for shipping method description -->
<tr class="row" visible="$context['$collapsible_' + method.method_code].opened">
    <td class="col" colspan="5" i18n="'Some description.'"/>
</tr>
<tr class="row row-error"
    if="method.error_message">
    <td class="col col-error" colspan="5">
        <div role="alert" class="message error">
            <div text="method.error_message"></div>
        </div>
        <span class="no-display">
                <input type="radio"
                       attr="'value' : method.method_code, 'id': 's_method_' + method.method_code" />
            </span>
    </td>
</tr>
</tbody>
```

How can I do this?

Thank's

Answer (score 0):

Your code is correct on:

```
public function collectRates(RateRequest $request)
{
   ...
   $method_colection->setData('prazo', $metodo['prazo']);
   ...
}
```

But in magento at the checkout or cart page, the rates are obtained by querying the api:

```
rest/default/V1/carts/mine/estimate-shipping-methods*
```

To load your additional data in the api you must override
Magento\Quote\Model\Cart\ShippingMethodConverter in your di.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">
    <preference for="Magento\Quote\Model\Cart\ShippingMethodConverter" type="{VENDOR}\{NAMESPACE}\Model\Cart\ShippingMethodConverter" />
</config>
```

In your file: {VENDOR}\{NAMESPACE}\Model\Cart\ShippingMethodConverter you can add your additional data:

```
<?php

namespace {VENDOR}\{NAMESPACE}\Model\Cart;

/**
 * Quote shipping method data.
 */
class ShippingMethodConverter extends \Magento\Quote\Model\Cart\ShippingMethodConverter
{

  /**
   * Converts a specified rate model to a shipping method data object.
   *
   * @param string $quoteCurrencyCode The quote currency code.
   * @param \Magento\Quote\Model\Quote\Address\Rate $rateModel The rate model.
   * @return array
   */
  public function modelToDataObject($rateModel, $quoteCurrencyCode)
  {
    $result = parent::modelToDataObject($rateModel, $quoteCurrencyCode);

    /** @var \Magento\Framework\Api\AbstractExtensibleObject $result */
    $result->setData('prazo', $rateModel->getPrazo());

    return $result->__toArray();
  }

}
```